# How will the transition from PoW to Casper's PoS work?

Tags: casper

How will the transition from PoW to Casper's PoS work? Is there a spec written? Have there been any tests? Has code or documentation been written?

Comment: The idea is to force a fork to PoS/Casper.  I'm upvoting the question but I think the questions are quite similar and it's good to have the answers in just one spot.

Answer (score 1):

A fork will be needed to allow PoS in the network. All statistics and analytics of proof of stake has not been announced fully in Ethereum, so we are all waiting for that information.

https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/11/25/proof-stake-learned-love-weak-subjectivity/

https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/08/01/introducing-casper-friendly-ghost/